# HtmlTableCellCollection.Add() needs NEW Cell instance everytime?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
    ContentPlaceHolder wrapperCPH = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    HtmlTable tblCumulativeCredits = (HtmlTable)wrapperCPH.FindControl("tblCumulativeCredits");
    //If your table is not inside of a ContentPlaceHolder, you can just test with "this.FindControl("yourHTMLTableID");

    HtmlTableRow tableRow = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell tableCellAmount = new HtmlTableCell();
    HtmlTableCell tableCellCurrency = new HtmlTableCell();

    tableCellAmount.InnerText = item.amount.ToString();
    tableCellCurrency.InnerText = item.currencyCode.code;

    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellAmount);
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellCurrency);
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellCurrency);

    tblCumulativeCredits.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tblCumulativeCredits" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th class="th">Amount</th>
        <th class="th">Currency1</th>
        <th class="th">Currency2</th>           
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now imagine I'm adding rows using this code sample in a loop and I know that my Currency1 = Currency2 in some case. So I'm using same Cell object as the above example. But there goes something interesting, if I add same currencies like the example; it only adds the first one, the third cell (Currency3) is empty.
It only adds the second currency if I create a **new** Cell instance, and add it:

```
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellAmount);
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellCurrency1);
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCellCurrency2);
```

I think this is the first time I saw that an "Add()" method is working this way. Shouldnt it be creating a new instance of the given parameter (cell object) under the hood? I'd appreciate if anyone can explain what is the logic behind this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with the implementation af the "Add" method, instead I think this happens during the rendering. 
Just remember that you are adding the same instance two times and that not only means the value of the cell (maybe also some kind of reference that exmplain the "overwriting" behavior).
So, you better create a new instance.

Cheers